# Filtering out 0-9 & dashes only?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create a regexp that targets any characters in my string that isn't `0-9` (numeric) or `-` (dash). What is wrong with my  below regexp?

Regex:

```
regex = '/^[0-9-]/g';
```

JS implementation:

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
```

Comment: Regexes are not strings.

Comment: Well aware of that, just showing my regexp implementation

Comment: If you're "well aware of that", then why is your regex a string?

Comment: @Industrial, you need to loose the single quotes (which is what Tomalak means).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant for your `^` to be *inside* the character class. Also, [regexes are not strings](http://jsfiddle.net/Wwsby/):

```
regex = /[^0-9-]/g;
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put '^' inside the brackets and escape '-', it being a special char.  Your regex should be

```
regex = /[^0-9\-]/g
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `-`.

Comment: No, at the start, or end of a character class, `-` does not need to be escaped. You don't even have to escape it directly after a range (`[a-c-A-C]`) or directly after a short-hand character class (`[\d-\w]`).

Comment: @Tomalak, your comment that it doesn't need to be escaped could be interpreted differently than you had meant. You mean that it does not need to be escaped in _this_ case, while your comment could be interpreted that it never needs escaping inside a class, which is not true (I know _you_ know this...).